# Adding the incoming edges of a vertex to a set property during a traversal

Tags: gremlin, directed-acyclic-graphs

What I would like to do is a depth first traversal, where on each step I add the incoming edge (actually the vertex) to a set. Ultimately I want each node in the step to have a list of incoming vertices that were traversed. Initially I was adding one to a simple property for each incoming edge :

```
g.V().has('Name', 'startnode').repeat(__.in()).emit().property('degree', union(values('degree'), constant(1)).sum())
```

I end up with a property ***degree*** which holds a count of incoming edges. I now want a set of incoming edges rather than just a count. something similar to :

```
g.V().has('Name', 'R1\\B').repeat(__.in()).emit().property(set, 'incoming', XXX)
```

It's that XXX. What do I need to set it to? i.e. the current incoming vertex in the traversal.

Comment: Do you want to add all edges that were traversed on the current path or only the last edge that led to the current vertex?

Comment: Just the last edge that led to the current vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get access to the edges, you need to traverse them explicitely.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('software').
           repeat(__.inE().as('e').outV()).
             emit().
           property(set, 'incoming', select(last, 'e')).iterate()
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[incoming:[e[9][1-created->3],e[8][1-knows->4]],name:[marko],age:[29]]
==>[name:[vadas],age:[27]]
==>[name:[lop],lang:[java]]
==>[incoming:[e[11][4-created->3],e[10][4-created->5]],name:[josh],age:[32]]
==>[name:[ripple],lang:[java]]
==>[incoming:[e[12][6-created->3]],name:[peter],age:[35]]
```

I wouldn't recommend storing whole edges though; edge ids might be fine.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('software').
           repeat(__.inE().as('e').outV()).
             emit().
           property(set, 'incoming', select(last, 'e').by(id)).iterate()
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[incoming:[9,8],name:[marko],age:[29]]
==>[name:[vadas],age:[27]]
==>[name:[lop],lang:[java]]
==>[incoming:[11,10],name:[josh],age:[32]]
==>[name:[ripple],lang:[java]]
==>[incoming:[12],name:[peter],age:[35]]
```

**UPDATE**

To collect the adjacent vertex ids, it would be:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('software').
           repeat(__.as('v').in()).
             emit().
           property(set, 'incoming', select(last, 'v').by(id)).iterate()
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[incoming:[3,4],name:[marko],age:[29]]
==>[name:[vadas],age:[27]]
==>[name:[lop],lang:[java]]
==>[incoming:[3,5],name:[josh],age:[32]]
==>[name:[ripple],lang:[java]]
==>[incoming:[3],name:[peter],age:[35]]
```

Comment: Nearly. Almost perfect. So that gives me a set of "incoming edges" for each vertex in the traversal. What I really need is a set of vertices where that edge originates from. So I either store that, or can I get that information from the edge? So for the example above, what I want is the following result :

Comment: ==>[incoming:[1],name:[marko],age:[29]]   ==>[incoming:[4],name:[josh],age:[32]]  ==>[incoming:[6],name:[peter],age:[35]]

Comment: That would be the `id` of the current vertex, but I think I know what you're after. Updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah perfect. I was nearly there myself, I just didn't have the __ before the "as". One question I would like to ask is the purpose of the iterate(). The only bit I don't quite understand.

Comment: In the console, I really just use to hide the traversal's output.